# GeoTools WFS Feature retrieval

Tags: wfs, java, geotools

I am trying to use GeoTools to retrieve the list of features served by a WFS. I am following the tutorial provided at http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/wfs.html.

The code that I have is as follows:

```
// Step 1 - connection parameters
//
Map connectionParameters = new HashMap();
connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", capabilitiesUrl.toString() );

// Step 2 - connection
DataStore data = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore( connectionParameters );

// Step 3 - discouvery
String typeNames[] = data.getTypeNames();
String typeName = typeNames[0];
SimpleFeatureType schema = data.getSchema( typeName );
System.out.println( "Schema Attributes:"+schema.getAttributeCount() );

// Step 4 - target
SimpleFeatureSource source = data.getFeatureSource( typeName );
System.out.println( "Metadata Bounds:"+ source.getBounds() );

SimpleFeatureCollection features = source.getFeatures();
SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = features.features();
while( iterator.hasNext() ){
    Feature feature = (Feature) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(feature.getName());
}
```

However, my DataStore object is always null. I have tried this using geotools version 9.1, version 10-SNAPSHOT and version 11-SNAPSHOT. I am using Maven to manage the dependancies. When I use version 11-SNAPSHOT, I keep getting a DataStoreFinder NoClassDefFound on running the above code. When using version 11-snapshot, I cannot see any of the geotools jars in the maven local repository which is probably why this error occurs. However, I have not yet managed to resolve it.

I have included the pom files below. The first POM results in the following error on running mvn clean install:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/data/DataStoreFinder
    at com.envitia.geopackage.geopackagecreator.dataharvestor.WFSDataHarvestor.getFeatureGeometries(WFSDataHarvestor.java:295)
    at com.envitia.geopackage.geopackagecreator.dataharvestor.WFSDataHarvestor.getFeatureType(WFSDataHarvestor.java:274)
    at com.envitia.geopackage.geopackagecreator.dataharvestor.WFSDataHarvestor.readData(WFSDataHarvestor.java:176)
    at com.envitia.geopackage.geopackagecreator.App.main(App.java:22)
```

POM 1:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample.harvestor</groupId>
    <artifactId>Creator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Creator</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>11-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-opengis</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>com.sample.harvestor.creator.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository> <!--Add the snapshot repository here-->
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>opengeo</id>
            <name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

The next POM does not return any errors on mvn install, but on running the application, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.envitia.geopackage.geopackagecreator.dataharvestor.WFSDataHarvestor.getFeatureGeometries(WFSDataHarvestor.java:298)
    at com.envitia.geopackage.geopackagecreator.dataharvestor.WFSDataHarvestor.getFeatureType(WFSDataHarvestor.java:274)
    at com.envitia.geopackage.geopackagecreator.dataharvestor.WFSDataHarvestor.readData(WFSDataHarvestor.java:176)
    at com.envitia.geopackage.geopackagecreator.App.main(App.java:22)
```

This NullPointer is due to the data object being null as mentioned earlier.

POM2:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample.harvestor</groupId>
    <artifactId>Harvestor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Harvestor</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>10-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-opengis</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>com.sample.temp.harvestor.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository> <!--Add the snapshot repository here-->
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>opengeo</id>
            <name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

`DataStoreFinder` is depricated in new versions. And the tutorial you mentioned is an old tutorial.
You can code in the following manner:

```
String getCapabilities = "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wfs?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&version=1.0.0";
Map connectionParameters = new HashMap();
connectionParameters.put("WFSDataStoreFactory:GET_CAPABILITIES_URL", getCapabilities);
WFSDataStoreFactory  dsf = new WFSDataStoreFactory();
try {
    WFSDataStore dataStore = dsf.createDataStore(connectionParameters);
    SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource("ali:Manategh_Tehran");
    SimpleFeatureCollection fc = source.getFeatures();
    while(fc.features().hasNext()){
        SimpleFeature sf = fc.features().next();
        System.out.println(sf.getAttribute("myname"));
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```